# Menu in nested fragment with viewpager not hiding correctly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-menu, android-nested-fragment

I have a view pager that display serval nested fragments.
Consider A,B and C are the fragments directly hold by the view pager.
And each A,B and C holds a fragment D which the option menu.
The problem is that, the menu item is correctly hided when switching page.
When A switch to B, there will be duplicated menu items.
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: show some of your code... how you add your `Fragments` within your `ViewPager`, your `ViewPager`'s adapter and so on...

Comment: I basically follow the guide http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html. But I am using ToolBar instead.